# Non-virtual destructor when using shared_ptr to opaque type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior

In the code below, `Base` is an abstract base class with non-virtual destructor.

`Derived`, a concrete type, can only be instantiated inside the `make_thing()` factory function (it's declaration and definition are visible exclusively from within the scope of `make_thing()`).

My understanding is that, since `std::shared_ptr<T>` stores the concrete deleter at the point of construction, it is well defined to delete `Derived` via `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.

This would not compile if `make_thing()` returned a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` and it would be undefined behavior if it returned `Base*`.

While the code works as expected, I wonder whether it contains Undefined Behavior.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
 public:
  void method() const noexcept { return this->do_method(); }

 protected:
  ~Base() noexcept { std::cout << "~Base()\n"; }

 private:
  virtual void do_method() const noexcept = 0;
};

std::shared_ptr<Base> make_thing() {
  class Derived final : public Base {
   public:
    ~Derived() noexcept { std::cout << "~Derived()\n"; }

   private:
    void do_method() const noexcept override {
      std::cout << "Derived::do_method()\n";
    }
  };

  return std::make_shared<Derived>();
};

int main() {
  // only way to instantiate Derived
  auto thing = make_thing();
  thing->method();
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ clang++ example.cpp -std=c++20
$ ./a.out
Derived::do_method()
~Derived()
~Base()
```

Comment: `do_method` being private in the base class looks suspiscious

Comment: @Den-Jason, except it isn't. Standard issue non-virtual interface pattern.

Comment: @Den-Jason: provided it is called from a public function I can see no problem.

Comment: Personally, if I already have one virtual function, making the destructor virtual has a very small marginal cost. At the very least it keeps the zealots off of you in code review.

Comment: @Den-Jason: See [Non-virtual interface design pattern in C#/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6481260/10077), for example.

Comment: Ah, thanks guys; Herb Sutter explains it well.  I've always presumed you need to make virtual methods at least protected.....http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: @Den-Jason • for small programs, the NVI pattern is overkill.  For larger programs, it is very useful.  Separation of concerns from the public facing API from the inheritance facing API.

Comment: Question is definitely a duplicate — apologies. Not only is it a near duplicate to the indicated question, but also to a question I myself asked seven years ago! I must be getting old…