# How to call the virtual method before calling overriden method outside the class?

Tags: c++, friend, virtual-inheritance

The obvious solution is:

```cpp
class GUI{
public:
    virtual void render() {
        //Common render code
    }
}

class MainGUI : public GUI {
private:
    void render() override {
        GUI::render();
        //MainGUI render code
    }
}

int main(...){
   GUI* mainGUI = new MainGUI();
   mainGUI->render();
}
```

`Common render code` will be executed before executing the `MainGUI render code`.

But what if I don't want to call `GUI::render();` in every class that inherits GUI? And how to open the virtual method `render()` only to the specific method?

My first thought was to use a separate method to call `Common render code` and then call the virtual method:

```cpp
class GUI{
public:
    void render(){
        //Common render code
        renderImpl();
    }
private:
    virtual void renderImpl() = 0;
}

class MainGUI : public GUI {
private:
    void renderImpl() override {
        //MainGUI render code
    }
}

int main(...){
   GUI* mainGUI = new MainGUI();
   mainGUI->render();
}
```

This code solves the first question, but not the second. I can make the non-virtual `render()` private, and then specify `main()` as a friend to open all the hidden methods and fields of the class.

But this solution could potentially lead to calling `renderImpl()` instead of `render()`. I mean the programmer's mistake.

So, how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for confusion. I couldn't formulate the question title correctly.

My main problem was related more to friendly classes than to virtual methods. @Jarod42's comment pointed me to right solution.

Comment: "But what if I don't want to call GUI::render(); in every class that inherits GUI?" why do you think you need to call it in every derived class? I mean what prevents you from not calling it?

Comment: It seems you have 2 questions... And so one question by question.

Comment: This is the way inherence and virtual functions work in C++.  You get the choice in the derived function whether or not to call the base class implementation and when (in the derived function- beginning, middle, end) you make the call.  Other languages enforce various rules, but don't have the flexibility.

Comment: *"And how to open the virtual method render() only to the specific method?"* [Pass key idiom](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/10/passkey-idiom/) allows to have more fined-grain options about friendship.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number for example, in the GUI I have some code that prepares rendering engine to render the GUI (set Shader Program, for example). If I skip the line with calling the base method, MainGUI will not be displayed due to the incorrect state of the rendering engine. This is just an example.

Comment: This *may* be a case for the [non-virtual interface idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481260/non-virtual-interface-design-pattern-in-c-c).

Answer (score 0):

Try this sort of Template method pattern where your `render()` method contains step (`internal_render`) you can `override`:

```
class GUI {
private:
    virtual void internal_render() = 0;
    void common_render() {
        std::cout << "Common render ";
    };
public:
    void render() {
        common_render();
        internal_render();
    }
};

class MainGUI : public GUI {

private:
    void internal_render() override {
        std::cout << "Derived render";
    }
};

int main() {
    GUI* mainGUI = new MainGUI();
    mainGUI->render();
}
```